# Ignoring NAs on period.apply

Tags: r, xts, na

I currently have a xts with multiple columns and rows, where some NAs can be present, just like seen bellow:

```
     utc          VR1_40 VR2_40 VR3_40  Q1_40   Q2_40   Q3_40
16.05.18 01:49:20   4   4   4   400 400 400
16.05.18 01:50:20   5   5   5   500 500 500
16.05.18 01:54:48   5   5   5   500 500 500
16.05.18 01:57:54   5   5   5   500 500 500
16.05.18 01:59:54   5   5   5   500 500 500
16.05.18 02:00:16   null    2   2   200 200 null
16.05.18 02:03:10   2   null    2   200 200 null
16.05.18 02:07:12   2   2   null    200 null    200
16.05.18 02:09:52   2   2   2   null    200 null
16.05.18 03:09:52   3   3   3   300 300 300
```

I  want to get a 10 minute average, so I apply the following code:

```
means.xts <- period.apply(ts, endpoints(ts, "mins", k=10), FUN=mean)
```

The problem is that a single NA will output NA for the whole 10 minute average.

```
                      VR1_40 Q1_40 VR2_40 Q2_40 VR3_40 Q3_40
2018-05-16 01:49:20      4   400      4   400      4   400
2018-05-16 01:59:54      5   500      5   500      5   500
2018-05-16 02:09:52     NA    NA     NA    NA     NA    NA
2018-05-16 03:09:52      3   300      3   300      3   300
```

Using na.omit like so

```
means.xts <- period.apply(na.omit(ts), endpoints(na.omit(ts), "mins", k=10), FUN=mean)
```

Will exclude the whole NA row from the result.

And defining a custom mean function like so

```
means.xts <- period.apply(na.omit(ts), endpoints(na.omit(ts), "mins", k=10), FUN = function(x){mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)})
```

Will average all the columns into a single one.

Seems something simple that I'm missing... any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: FUN = function(x){colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)} ?

Comment: That's it... simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set na.rm as True.
Like this:

```
means.xts <- period.apply(na.omit(ts), endpoints(na.omit(ts), "mins", k=10), FUN = mean,na.rm=T)
```